# Exception filters and handlers not called on 405

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

In my WebApi app, I've got an exception filter

```
    config.Filters.Add(New AppExceptionFilterAttribute)
```

The filter simply reformats the exception into a format that I prefer.  This has been working fine when there's an application error. But today I got an error I hadn't seen before, a 405, and for some reason the filter is simply not called.

I tried adding a global exception handler:

```
    config.Services.Replace(GetType(ExceptionHandling.IExceptionHandler), New AppExceptionHandler())
```

But this isn't called either! It seems that when I get a 405, WebApi insists on handling this itself, and not calling my filter or my handler, and so I can't reformat the exception the way I want, and this is really annoying.

How can I hook that 405 error?

Comment: Is this request reaching your action at all? I thought 405 is thrown at server level Method not allowed by the server. http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E405.html

Comment: No, it's not reaching the action at all, but it is throwing a framework exception, and I'm trying to filter that exception, so I can format the response the way I'd like.

Answer (score 0):

Exception handling in Web Api is targeted for `unhandled` exceptions and so responses like `404 Not Found` and `405 Method Not Allowed` are not considered.

Comment: So there's no way to customize the response in those cases? That seems surprising given how pluggable everything in WebApi is in general.